# Increasing Stack Space, Independent the Machine - Java

Tags: java, stack

My algorithm needs to use more stack space than allowed by default.  Do I have to increase the stack space on every machine, or is there a way to include it in the class so it will run smoothly on each machine.

Comment: I would change the algorithm so it doesn't use as much stack space. You can't increase the stack size of a running program even in C.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - The algorithm involves a depth first search, that is why is so intensive, but I will try doing it iteratively now...

Comment: Doing it iteratively isn't always easy, but if you can do it, it won't have this problem.  You may find you can reduce the depth of recursion depending on what you are doing. e.g. you can sum a list -> `list.get(0) + sum(list.subList(1, list.size())` which has a depth of list.size() or `sum(list.subList(0, list.size()/2)) + sum(list.subList(list.size()/2, list.size()))` which has a depth of log2(list.size())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your latter approach won't work - the stack space is a startup parameter, which is used to allocate space to the Java process itself.

By the time everything has been set up to load and execute the class, by definition the process already exists and its stack size has already been determined.  You can't modify `Xss` at runtime.

Usually what you'd do though is distribute a startup script which launches your application with appropriate memory parameters.  How is your class being invoked?  If it's a library then it's the *application's* job to ensure enough memory is allocated, arguably you can just list it as a requirement in your documentation.

In an extreme case you could use `Process` to spawn a completely new Java process with the startup parameters you desire - however this would be very error prone, would require an assumption that `java` was on the path (or that the same directory structure exists everywhere), that you have permissions to create new processes, that sufficient memory/filehandles exist for this new process, etc.  It isn't something I'd want to do, but if you exhaust *all* other options it might tide you over in a pinch.

Comment: So the Xmx paramater needs to be run on every machine before loading my program?

Comment: You have to deliver your application with startup script (start.sh, start.bat). This scipt will start the application with specified parameters. Xmx value will be specified there. So you won't have to change anything manually. Startup script will do it for you every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "run on each machine".  Your class will be loaded inside a JVM, that was launched *somehow*, and at the time this JVM was created the stack size parameters will have been processed.  You need to ensure that these JVMs are created with a large enough stack.  How you actually do this depends entirely on how your class is being executed/imported/what have you.  If it's an application for which you distribute a launch script, then you just need to make a single change to the launch script for example.

Comment: Xmx doesn't set stack size but heap size. It's Xss.

Answer (score 2):

Stack size is JVM configuration, so it will need to be set on every machine you run on. There's no way to do it from inside Java.

However, it sounds like you should focus on reducing stack use. The simple way is to focus on reducing the size of each stack fame, and the number of frames allocated (that is, the depth of recursion). The harder but more powerful way is to convert recursion to iteration, using an explicit stack allocated  on the heap.